# How to use Hopper to debug wine apps

Tags: debugging, decompilation, wine

I'm running Linux Mint , and I try to use the linux Hopper to debug a windows exe .
Does anyone knows a way to debug in Hopper the applications that runs uder wine ?

For example like : winedbg --gdb /home/v/Documents/putty.exe

Comment: tried the official support?